# 6V DC Motor Overheat

Tags: motor, dc

I am totally new to electronics, so be patient with me please, it is very basic question :)

I have a 6V DC motor which I reused from an old device, that means I don't know its specs. I connected it to a power supply provides 6V DC, 2.3 A max. the motor worked great with a good rotation speed but extremely overheated after 3 minutes. So I connected it to a 5V with 1 A max, it worked fine without overheating but with lower RPM.

My question is: How to increase the rotation speed of the motor with the 5V, 1 A power source ***or*** How to prevent the overheating of the motor with the 6V, 2.3 A power source?

Comment: Very simply, you need a different motor. Clearly, 6V is too much for that one.

Comment: The no-load rpm of the motor is the fastest that it will go for that particular configuration.

Comment: Why 6V is too much for the motor? it was originally working by 4x1.5V AA batteries which means 6V dc, anyway I use now a 5V with 1A max. current with very light load on it (plastic fan blade) and it still slow.

Comment: The original application that the motor was used in may have had a lower duty cycle, which would have allowed the average temperature to remain low. 6V is clearly too much for continuous duty cycle.

Comment: Batteries have internal resistance, more of it than a typical power supply.    The builtin resistance in batteries will cause a voltage drop as soon as current is drawn, while the power supply will work harder to maintain 6 volts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this as an answer because though I am very much interested in the question, I am unable to comment and clarify some points.

So here is how I think you can debug,

1. Please use a multimeter ( or ammeter ) and measure the currents drawn by the motor at 5V and 6V respectively.
2. If the current drawn at 5V is around 1A and the current drawn at 6V is higher ( which is how I expect it would be ), then the simple reason would be that the nominal operatig current of the motor, without causing spikes in temperature, is 1A.

   As for why it works with 4 x 1.5V batteries, the toy or the object from where you removed the motor, generally use current limiters ( or sometimes power dividers ) for damage prevention. A motor is generally a low resistance device ( try testing for 'short circuit' using a multimeter across the motor terminals. It'll beep! ). Hence it usually draws a high amount of current. But current limiters restrict this flow in the toy. Whereas when you connect a 6V DC supply directly, the current might reach for the full capacity of dc source ( 2.3A for 6V here ).

   Also remember the power dissipated is proportional to the square of the current. Hence slight changes will result in drastic changes in heat generated.
3. In case the above observation was not made and then I have no other suggestion but to replace the motor, as *waltx* said.

Please comment what you find.

Comment: I think that you've got the right answer. The multimeter shows 1 A with the 5V PS, and shows 1.93 A with the 6V. Now, the question is how to implement a current limiter to the circuit with the power source of 6V DC so that the heat generated doesn't exceed the normal conditions?

Comment: Please check the following link to build one: [link](http://www.physics.unlv.edu/~bill/PHYS483/current_lim.pdf). It is a very simple current limiter. Besides this, there are many other interesting designs that limit current, available online.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a permanent magnet, brush DC motor. The motor current increased rapidly with a 1 volt increase. 5 volts at 1 amp to 6 volts at 2.3 amps under no load conditions. Typically, the motor current and motor voltage are more linearly related under no load conditions.

The motor, most likely, has bearing damaged and brush or commutator damage.

Comment: We don't know how much current the motor was taking, just how much current the power supply could provide.